# Variable scope in a module

Tags: javascript

I'm writing my first javascript module, and there is something that I don't understand with the scope variables. Here is my module :

```
var Module = (function () {

    var myString ='a';

    var changeString = function () {
        myString ='b';
        console.log(myString);
    };

    return {
      changeString: changeString,
      myString:myString
    };

  })();
```

Now if I do :

```
Module.myString;             // returns 'a'
Module.changeString();       // returns 'b'
Module.myString;             // returns 'a'
```

For me , the last command should return 'b' because I've changed myString with the changeString method. I don't understand why, since myString is declared outside the changeString method, so the scope seems ok. I would like to understand why it behaves like this, and how to make a method which overwrites the value of my variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This 'var Module = (function () {...' returns an object (something like an object with a function and a value, from myString). It does not return a reference to the variable myString.

Comment: FWIW the problem has nothing to do with scope but rather with understanding the difference between variables and values and that JavaScript is *pass-by-value*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes a copy of `myString` at the time the object is created:

```
return {
  changeString: changeString,
  myString:myString
}
```

You can use a getter to return the local variable dynamically and that will give you the behaviour you expected:

```
return {
  changeString: changeString,
  get myString() { 
    return myString;
  }
}
```

Full example:

```js
var Module = (function () {

    var myString ='a';

    var changeString = function () {
        myString ='b';
        console.log(myString);
    };

    return {
      changeString: changeString,
      get myString() { 
        return myString;
      }
    }

})();

console.log( Module.myString );
Module.changeString();
console.log( Module.myString );
```

Comment: *"This takes a copy..."*: I just want to mention that this is not necessarily so per implementation. The property and variable could very well point to the same string in memory, but as soon as a reassignment occurs, certainly *then* a different memory location is used, not *mutating* the string that is already there.

Comment: I like this approach because, while it is slightly more complicated than necessary, it avoids duplicating `myString` and maintains a reference to a single source. Plus there is no issue if you do `var changeStr = Module.changeString; changeStr();` unlike my answer, which requires intuition about how `this` works.

Answer (score 3):

The anonymous function is only executed once, and the object returned by it is thus also only evaluated once: it is an object with a string property `myString` which is a primitive value -- it will not change if the variable `myString` is changed later.

If you wanted the behaviour like you expected it, then you should keep a reference in the Module to the object you return, and then *mutate* that object when the string property needs to change:

```
var Module = (function () {    
    var changeString = function () {
        obj.myString = 'b'; // mutation of obj!
        console.log(obj.myString);
    };
    var obj = {
         changeString: changeString,
         myString: 'a';
    };
    return obj; // we have a reference to this object
})();
```

Comment: We already have a reference to the object ;) via `Module` [or simply `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871457/1541563)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, true, but I feel this way I could focus the explanation to the essentials without complicating it maybe for the OP with the concept of `this` or a self reference to `Module` within `Module`.

Comment: I think I got it, that's intersting. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

As is said in other answers, because `myString` is a primitive, its value is copied from the scope to the member value of the anonymous object returned. In order to access the externally available copy of `myString` from the `changeString()` method, you can reference the anonymous object assigned to `Module` using the `this` keyword:

```js
var Module = (function() {

  var myString = 'a';

  var changeString = function() {
    // `Module.changeString()` causes `this === Module` inside here
    this.myString = 'b';
  };

  return {
    changeString: changeString,
    myString: myString
  };
})();

console.log(Module.myString);             // returns 'a'
Module.changeString();
console.log(Module.myString);             // returns 'b'
```

Using ES6 syntax, there are a few shortcuts you can take to simplify this approach:

```js
var Module = (() => {

  let myString = 'a';

  return {
    // ES6 for `myString: myString,`
    myString,
    // ES6 for `changeString: function () {`
    changeString () {
      this.myString = 'b';
    }
  };
})();

console.log(Module.myString); // returns 'a'
Module.changeString();
console.log(Module.myString); // returns 'b'
```

Comment: I think this is probably exactly what the OP wants, rather than my solution using a getter.

Comment: @Paulpro thanks for the edit, otherwise my answer would have looked pretty dumb.

Answer (score 1):

You see this behaviour because you `return` a fresh object.

The string `myString` gets copied because it is a primitive value.

You can achieve your goal with a few adjustments:

```
var Module = function() {
    var myString = 'a';

    this.changeString = function() {
        myString = 'b';
    };

    this.getString = function() {
        return myString;
    };
};

var mod = new Module;

console.log(mod.getString()); // a
mod.changeString();
console.log(mod.getString()); // b
```